# Can we create a steady current from just one electron in motion?

Tags: electromagnetism

I have seen a problem calculating the magnetic field of just one electron rotating in a circular loop, the calculation went like this, if n is the number of revolutions the electron makes per second, then $$ B=\frac{μ_{0}ne}{2r} $$
My question is how I=ne is the steady current?

Comment: Does your source mention it being an approximation? Which it likely is.

Comment: It doesn't mention it, but why would I approximate it this way? I mean B for a circular conductor with N turns has the following formula B=μ₀NI/2r, why would I choose N to be 1 and I=ne? and what does it even mean when I say I=ne,,,I mean by definition, I is the amount of charge passing through the conductor's cross section in a sec,  so saying that I=ne doesn't make any sense!

Comment: Ok, so the question is not about the "steady", but about the concrete value. That was unclear to me so far.

Comment: Steady current by definition is a current that has a constant magnitude at any point of a conductor. And the magnetic field formulas use the value of this steady current. However, in this case of circulating electron, the book still calculates a magnetic field using a steady current defined as I=ne, so my question is can just one electron create a steady current? and why this current is defined as I=ne?

Comment: The electron doesn't generate a steady field, it will be emitting an EM wave. Your book will be considering the _average_ magnetic field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an approximation, and probably not a very good one. For a single classical point particle the fields are given by the [Lienard Wiechert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Li%C3%A9nard%E2%80%93Wiechert_potential#Field_computation) fields:

$$\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{r}, t) = \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \left(\frac{q c(\boldsymbol{\beta}_s \times \mathbf{n}_s)}{\gamma^2 (1-\mathbf{n}_s \cdot \boldsymbol{\beta}_s)^3 |\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s|^2} + \frac{q \mathbf{n}_s \times \Big(\mathbf{n}_s \times \big((\mathbf{n}_s - \boldsymbol{\beta}_s) \times \dot{\boldsymbol{\beta}_s}\big) \Big)}{(1 - \mathbf{n}_s \cdot \boldsymbol{\beta}_s)^3 |\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s|} \right)_{t_r} $$
where $\boldsymbol{\beta}_s(t) = \frac{\mathbf{v}_s(t)}{c}$, $\mathbf{n}_s(t) = \frac{\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t)}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}_s(t)|}$ and $\gamma(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - |\boldsymbol{\beta}_s(t)|^2}}$ (the Lorentz factor).

The first term is essentially the relativistic Biot Savart law for a point charge and the second term is the radiation due to the acceleration of the point charge. For a classical point charge in uniform circular motion at $n$ revolutions per second, both terms will be sinusoids at the frequency $n$.

The approximation in the problem is to use the non-relativistic Biot savart law for a steady current loop. So for that approximation to work, $n$ needs to be high enough that the detector cannot detect the variation in the B field, but low enough that $\gamma \approx 1$, and also low enough that the radiation term is negligible.

Personally, I suspect that the last requirement, in particular, will be difficult to achieve. If $n$ is high enough to exceed the frequency response of the detector, then it is likely that the radiation field will be non-negligible.

Note that a similar approximation is made when calculating the precession of perihelion for planets in the solar system. In that case it works because the precession is measured over centuries, and also the gravitational radiation is negligible.